# How to clear imagekit cache

Tags: django, django-imagekit

I'm using imagekit on S3 with a NonValidatingImageCacheBackend backend. I recently changed the sizes on one of my specs and realized that imagekit didn't regenerate new specs because the optimistic backend is blinding retrieving the old cached images.

How can I force imagekit to regenerate the entire cache?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out (after reading [this](https://github.com/jdriscoll/django-imagekit/issues/145)): Say you have a ImageSpec called `thumbnail`, then simply call the `generate` method on that object. It'll regenerate the thumbnail file for you.